# Regex to find and replace ES6 bare modules with relative paths

Tags: regex

I have a load of npm/Yarn JS libraries that use *bare module* specifiers, like:

```
import { ComponentName } from '@org/component-name';
```

I'm trying to build a regex to replace these with relative paths JS can understand:

```
import { ComponentName } from '../@org/component-name/component-name.js';
```

I'm doing this with a regex, which currently looks [like this](https://regex101.com/r/giqmTO/14):

```
/(?<key>import|export)\s+(?:(?:\s*(?<alias>[\w\r\n\t,{}\s\* ]+)\s*)\s*from)?\s*(?:["']?(?<ref>[@\w\s\\\/\-\.]+)["']?)/gm
```

So far this:

- Uses named groups for each part of the syntax
- Finds `import` or `export` keyword.
- Finds the optional multiline alias/es
- Finds the reference

I can then find all the matches, find the reference on disk, figure out the relative path and insert that instead.

I'm doing this in C# on .NET Core.

How can I exclude sample `import` statements that are inside comments?

This doesn't currently include dynamic `import` statements, and it probably should, but as they don't have explicit aliases they might be better as a separate pass.

Is there a better way to handle this replacement in .NET?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following regex:

```
(?<key>import|export)\s+(?:(?<alias>[\w,{}\s\*]+)\s+from)?\s*(?:(["'])?(?<ref>[@\w\s\\\/.-]+)\3?)\s*;
```

- The alias part contained some unnecessary characters since the `\s` shorthand character already contains `\r\n\t`,
  and
- it's not required to escape all special characters in character classes, e.g. the `-` when it is the last item in the `ref` capture group.
- we can use a back reference to ensure the optional closing quote is of the same type as the opening one.
- Finally, I've added the semi-colon as end-anchor. This should solve the problem of imports in comments.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/EauTBN/1)

Comment: Cheers! That's really helpful. Unfortunately not all JS module authors terminate lines with `;`, so I can't rely on that as the end anchor.

Comment: That demo only works because the comments don't have a `;`, for instance `/* import { ComponentName } from '@org/component-name'; */` matches, and `import { ComponentName } from '@org/component-name'` does not.